# Perl, SAX and system entity

Tags: perl, entity, sax

I need to parse a XML file in Perl. One part of file is stored separately and it is inserted as system entity. The problem is quite common, though. However I'm unable to get any information how to solve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE RootNode [
    <!ENTITY externalContent SYSTEM "ext.txt">
]>
<RootNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../release/bin/schenma.xsd">
    &externalContent;
</RootNode>
```

When parsing this file using Pure Perl SAX, I get only information about elements and characters. Entity is handled as charecters. It is replaced with the quoted text, also it is replaced with `ext.txt` like internal entity. The SYSTEM keyword seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Is it critical to use Pure Perl SAX?
I've tried [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0014/LibXML.pod) and [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm), both of them processed XML with external entities correctly.

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $document = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'file.xml');
print $document->toString();
```